# jQuery toggle content, multiple active conditions

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hidden, visible

I would appreciate some assistance with a content toggle.

I currently have 2 tabs that toggle content - one must be set to focus at any one time and an additional class of active appended when the selected `.content-drawer` is visible.

Whilst my efforts below work when operating single tabs, the active state doesn't work when switching between states as the :visible condition fires at the wrong time.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Here's my current [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DcP7p/)

```
    $('.content-drawer').hide();

    $('.tab').click(function() {
        var target = $(this.rel);
            $('.content-drawer').not(target).slideUp();
            target.delay(500).slideToggle();
            $('.tabs > li.focus').removeClass('focus');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active focus');

    if ( $('.content-drawer:visible').length ) {
       $('.tabs > li.active').removeClass('active');
    }
    return false;
});​


<ul class="tabs">
   <li class="focus">
       <a href="#" rel="#calc" class="tab"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Calculator</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a href="#" rel="#info" class="tab"><i class="icon-info"></i>Info</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="content-drawer" id="calc">
    <p>Calc Content</p>    
</div>
<div class="content-drawer" id="info">
    <p>Info Content</p>    
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not fully understand what your problem is, but as i see you have some problem with async/callback. why not use `animate` and its `callback` function then (instead of delay, from comments at api.jquery.com/delay/ i see that is possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    $('.content-drawer').hide();

$('.tab').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $(this.rel);
    $this.closest('li').addClass('active focus');
    // Add the classes to the closest li of the clicked anchor
    $('.tab').not($this).closest('li').removeClass('active focus');
    // Remove the classes for the non-clicked items
    $('.content-drawer').not(target).slideUp();
    // Slideup the other contents
    target.delay(500).slideToggle();
    // Toggle the current content
    if (target.is(':visible')) {
        // Only if the target is visible remove the active class
        $this.closest('li').removeClass('active');
    } 
    return false;
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DcP7p/2/)**